# how to show message if only entered password is wrong?

Tags: php

please help me to display message if only entered password is wrong, when entered username is wrong it shows `"wrong username"`,i want to do the same for `password` when it is wrong, it has to display `"wrong password"`. here is

my code :

```
  if ( $pass===$dbpass && $id===$dbid ) {

      $show=mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id'");
      while ( $row=mysql_fetch_array($show)) {
        echo '<center><span style="font-size:50px;font-family:  HelveticaNeueLTW20;padding-top:50px;line-height:0.5em;color:red;text-shadow: 2px   2px 4px #000000;">'.$row['name'].'</span></center>';
        echo '<center><span style="font-size:20px;font-family:   HelveticaNeueLTW20;color:white;line-height:2.5em;">'.'- المعهد يتمنى لكم مسيرة   موفقة -'.'</span></center>';
    }

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id'");
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row ["images"]; ?>" <?php "  </td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
     }
      else
         echo ('<span style="font-size:40px;color:red;font-family:f45;text-  shadow: 2px 2px 4px white;">' . '<center dir="rtl" lang="ar">عذراً<br> لقد أَدخلت رقم هويتك خاطئاً...<br>المرجو المحاولة مجددا</center>' . '</span>');
      }

      if ( $pass!=$dbpass) {
    echo "grzegrzgzrg";
      }
     else
      die('<span style="color:red;font-size:40px;font-family:f45;text-   shadow: 2px 2px 4px white;">' . '<center dir="rtl" lang="ar">عذراً<br> المعلومات المدرجة ليست مسجلة في قاعدة بيانات المعهد!!</center>' . '</span>');
      }
```

Comment: Don't do this.  If the login fails, just tell the user that the login has failed.  Don't give an attacker more information than they already have.

Comment: You also should think about updating your driver and using parameterized queries.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard: You have that links for mysql, pdo and mysqli memorized by now? Hahaha :P

Comment: I do @ChrisG ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯